# sql: select list of columns

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to pass an str or list argument and want that sql knows how to treat it.
Example of `list_col='date1, date2, date3, date4'` and at the end i want to have dataframe
date1, date2, date3, id

```
query = """
    SELECT {list_col} AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris' as {list_col}, {table}.{id}
    FROM {table} 
    ORDER BY {table}.{id}
"""

def fun_query(table_name, list_col, id):
    return query.format(table=table_name, list_col=list_col, id=id)
```

Does anyone knows how to do it please?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: how to pass a list in {list_col}

Comment: There is no easy way to do this.  The `AT TIME ZONE` clauses should appear along with each column, or else it should not be a hard coded string in your template.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah true, do you know how to do it please?

Comment: the AT TIME ZONE i want to apply on date1, date2, date3, date4.

Comment: i did SELECT {listeee} from table AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris', {table}.{id}
FROM {table} 
ORDER BY {table}.{id}.

Comment: You could try to use a list comprehension to convert a list like `['date1', 'date2']` into `['date1 AT TIME ZONE', 'date2 AT TIME ZONE']`, then use `", ".join(the_list)` to convert it into a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted this is not doable in a way you suggested because both `AT TIME ZONE` and `AS` clauses should appear along with each column. I would suggest doing something like this.

```
query = """
    SELECT {date_cols_as_tz}, {table}.{id}
    FROM {table} 
    ORDER BY {table}.{id}
"""


def fun_query(table_name, list_col, id, tz="'Europe/Paris'"):
    date_cols_as_tz = ",".join((f"{c} AT TIME ZONE {tz} as {c}" for c in list_col))
    return query.format(date_cols_as_tz=date_cols_as_tz, table=table_name, list_col=list_col, id=id)
```

When you call e.g. `fun_query("my_table", ["date1", "date2"], "table_id")` and print it you get following query:

```
SELECT date1 AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris' as date1,date2 AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris' as date2, my_table.table_id
FROM my_table 
ORDER BY my_table.table_id
```

The major changes are:

- create `date_cols_as_tz` inside the `fun_query`
- use real list for `list_col` parameter (not string like `"date1,date2"` but list like `["date1", "date2"]`)
- added optional `tz` parameter to the function

The advantage of this solution is that you can easily change the timezone by using different value for `tz` instead of hard coded value.

Also note that this function expects that all columns in `list_col` are dates (but that's probably what you expect if I understood your question correctly).

Comment: Thank  you ^^ i had error when testing your suggestion **E       LINE 2: SELECT ['date1', 'date2'], tab1.id**

Comment: @tamo007 could you post here how did you call `fun_query`? (What were your parameters look like?)